# How to keep precision of gmpy2 mpfr in Numpy matrix operation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiprecision, gmpy

I am using Multiple-precision Rationals(mpfr) object in Numpy matrix,

```
matrix([[ mpfr('-366998.93593422093364191959435957721088073331222596080623233278164906447646654043966366647797',300),
     mpfr('-366997.28868432286431885359868309613943011772698563764930700121744888472828510537502286003536',300),
     mpfr('-366997.28868432286431885359868309613943011772698563764930700121744888472828510537502286003536',300),
     mpfr('-366997.28868432286431885359868309613943011772698563764930700121744888472828510537502310955189',300),
     mpfr('-366997.33936304224917822062156336656390364691713762458391131405889211470102834400572590888586',300),
     mpfr('-366997.28868432286431885359868309613943011772698563764930700121744888472828510537502286003536',300)],
    [ mpfr('-40813927.104656436832435886099653290386078894027773129049451436960078610548203287954114434382',300),
     mpfr('-10418349883335.380900703935580692318458974868691020694148304775624032110383967472053357462067',300),
     mpfr('-40813927.104656436832435886099653290386078894027773129049451436960078610548203287954114434382',300),
     mpfr('-40813927.104656436832435886099653290386078894027773129049451436960078610548203287954114434382',300),
     mpfr('-40813927.104656436832435886099653290386078894027773129049451436960078610548203287954114434382',300),
     mpfr('-40813927.104656436832435886099653290386078894027773129049451436960078610548203287954114434382',300)]], dtype=object)
```

but when compute the inverse of the matrix, I will lose the precision.

```
In [10]: a.I
Out[10]:
matrix([[ -5.44966727e-07,   1.91970239e-14],
        [  1.06745086e-11,  -9.59848660e-14],
        [ -5.44964281e-07,   1.91969377e-14],
        [ -5.44964281e-07,   1.91969377e-14],
        [ -5.44964356e-07,   1.91969404e-14],
        [ -5.44964281e-07,   1.91969377e-14]])
```

So how to keep precision of mpfr?
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, `numpy` uses the LAPACK libraries and has to convert the matrix elements to the standard `double` type. You may want to try `mpmath` for multiple precision matrix inversion.

Comment: Is there any way to use mpfr in Numpy? Because matrix operation in mpmath is slower than that of numpy . and I also want to keep the precision. Thanks

Comment: @PytLab The reason numpy is faster is because it uses the floating-point types that are implemented in hardware. They have fixed precision but are very fast. Once you start using arbitrary precision arithmetic, performance will be slower.